# Inserting data into BAPIRET2_TAB structure

Tags: abap

My method is using an export parameter of type BAPIRET2_TAB. I need to fill the values of this structure, but I cant access the structure directly. For example, parameter-message = 'text', etc.

How can I do this?

These are the parameters I need to pass:

```
lv_msg_line. type i
lv_syntax_text. //Error message
```

And this is syntax checker.

syntax-check for l_tab_code

```
  program   lv_progname
  message   l_error_message
  line      l_error_line
  word      l_error_word
  id 'ERR'  table l_tab_errors.
```

Comment: Do you need something like ASSIGN COMPONENT?

Comment: This makes no sense whatsoever. Please add the complete code with a complete, un-mangled error message.

Comment: `BAPIRET2_TAB` is not a structure but rather a table type.

Comment: Thanks guys, this was the fault!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like said above in the comments, BAPIRET2_TAB is not a structure, and therefore cannot have its components accessed directly via STRUCTURE-FIELD paradigm.

What you need is to declare an structure like this

```
DATA error_line TYPE LINE OF BAPIRET2_TAB.
```

Then, you can use it to fill the data in...

```
error_line-program = sy-repid.
error_line-id = sy-msgid.
```

... and so forth. Then, lastly, you append the error_line item to your BAPIRET2_TAB.

```
APPEND error_line TO bapi2tab.
CLEAR error_line.
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem!

Comment: @HardijsĶirsis great! can you please mark it as the right answer? tks!

Comment: @HardijsĶirsis this link will help you http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work